# Delete only the last digit after a specific sign when the sign (_) is present multiple times in a string

Tags: text-processing

I have a list of string in a text file:

```
AY498934.1_cds_AAS79865.1_1_1
AY498934.1_cds_AAS79865.1_1_2
AY498934.1_cds_AAS79865.1_1_3
```

I want to delete everything that comes after the last '_'.

Expected Results:

```
AY498934.1_cds_AAS79865.1_1
AY498934.1_cds_AAS79865.1_1
AY498934.1_cds_AAS79865.1_1
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is it always the last 2 characters?

Comment: sed 's/_5 //'.. I have used this command so far to remove the last digit such as 5 for this case but there are digits till 358. e.g.  AY498934.1_cds_AAS79865.1_1_358 or AY498934.1_cds_AAS79865.1_267_324. I just want to delete the numbers after the last "_".

Comment: and I want the output as AY498934.1_cds_AAS79865.1_1 or AY498934.1_cds_AAS79865.1_267

Comment: Are these originally _filenames_? In that case, it may be unnecessary to store them in a file. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I see four ***different*** problems here.  (1) The one in the title: delete only the last digit after '\_' when the '\_' is present multiple times in a string (which is unclear).  (2) The one stated in the body: delete everything that comes after the last '\_'.  (3) The one stated in [this comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/564539/80216#comment1049681_564539): delete the numbers after the last "\_".  (4) The one *illustrated:* delete the last '_' and everything after it. … … … … … … … … P.S. The use of the word “sign” in the title is pretty confusing.

Answer (score 5):

```
sed 's/_[^_]*$//' < file
```

Replace `_` followed by 0 or more (`*`) characters other than `_` (`[^_]`) followed by the end of the line `$` with *nothing*.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way:

```
sed -nr 's/(.*)_.*/\1/p' file
```

Match greedily (the longest string that matches) all characters up to `_` (which will be referred to as \1), followed by the rest of the line and replace it by the group \1.

Without the -r argument back-references (like \1) won't work.

The option -n toggles off the usual printing of every thing in the pattern space after all the sed commands have been executed.

```
cat file
AY498934.1_cds_AAS79865.1_1_1
AY498934.1_cds_AAS79865.1_1_2
AY498934.1_cds_AAS79865.1_1_3


sed -nr 's/(.*)_.*/\1/p' file
AY498934.1_cds_AAS79865.1_1
AY498934.1_cds_AAS79865.1_1
AY498934.1_cds_AAS79865.1_1
```